# computeDistanceBetween not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code:

```
function checkDistance(circle, beacon) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              };
              document.getElementById('latField').value = pos.lat;
              document.getElementById('lngField').value = pos.lng;            
              map.setCenter(pos);
              userCircle.setCenter(pos);
              modalmap.setCenter(pos);
              console.log("testend");
              var centercircle = circle.getCenter();
              console.log(centercircle);
              var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(centercircle, pos);
              console.log(distance);
            var radius = circle.getRadius();
            console.log(radius);
            if (distance <= radius) {
                circle.addListener('click', function() {
                    post('claimcreds.php', {id: beacon.id, cid: <?php echo $uid ?>, uid: beacon.uid, lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng, claimattempt: "true"});
            });
        }
            })
        }
```

Both `pos` and `centercircle` appear to be properly returning as`google.maps.LatLng`s, however `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` doesn't seem to want to return anything. I don't get any errors in the console, but nothing comes out of the `console.log(distance);` statement.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible that you get e.g. the output for `centerCircle`, but  no error.

`computeDistanceBetween` expects as arguments `google.maps.LatLng`-**instances**, but you provide via `pos` a `LatLng`-**literal**.

Use:

```
var distance 
   = google.maps.geometry.spherical
      .computeDistanceBetween(centercircle, 
                              new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat,pos.lng));
```

Comment: `(51.5073509, -0.12775829999998223) { lat=function(),  lng=function(),  toString=function(),  more...}` is `centerCircle`, `Object { lat=51.5056344,  lng=-0.32404279999999996}` is `pos`. I'll try your code, thanks :)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this worked PERFECTLY :) I would never have realized haha!